# Prepending a function docstring with a decorator in python

Tags: python, decorator, docstring

How would you be able to prepend a functions docstring with a decorator?

```
def g(func):
    someOtherDocString = "That is great"
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
return wrap

@g
def f():
""" This is awesome """
```

result:

```
>>>help(f)

Help on function f in module __main__:

f()
    That is great
    That is awesome
```

All the help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried magic `__doc__`:

```
from functools import wraps

def g(func):
    func.__doc__ = "That is great" + func.__doc__

    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```